# Delegates: passing messages between 4 layers

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I have previously used delegates to talk between 2 layers, my Base layer would send messages up to my GUI layer. I have since added another 2 layers between them and it is proving difficult for the 4 layers to "talk to each other". The task class is run on it's own thread.

Base Layer (generates messages and passes them Up):

```
public class APIWrapper
{
    public delegate void UsrMsgDelegate(string msg);

    private UsrMsgDelegate UsrMsg;
    public void MsgRedirect(UsrMsgDelegate msgHandler)
    {
        UsrMsg = msgHandler;
    }
    // Send a message with UsrMsg("message");
}
```

Task (Where almost all of the logic is done), generates messages and passes them up.

```
public class Task
{
    public delegate void UsrMsgDelegate(string msg);
    APIWrapper base;
    public Task(APIWrapper apiWrapper)
    {
        base = apiWrapper;
    }
    private UsrMsgDelegate UsrMsg;
    public void MsgRedirect(UsrMsgDelegate msgHandler)
    {
        UsrMsg = msgHandler;
    }
    // Send a message with UsrMsg("message");
}
```

TaskManager (I plan on adding extra tasks (this will manage all of them)). This just passes messages up to the GUI

```
public class TaskManager
{
    public delegate void UsrMsgDelegate(string msg);
    APIWrapper base;
    Task task;
    public Task()
    {
        base = new APIWrapper();
        base.MsgRedirect(this.UsrMsg);
        task = new Task(base);
        task.MsgRedirect(this.UsrMsg);
    }
    private UsrMsgDelegate UsrMsg;
    public void MsgRedirect(UsrMsgDelegate msgHandler)
    {
        UsrMsg = msgHandler;
    }
}
```

GUI (all messages are passed here)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TaskManager tm;

    public Form1()
    {
        tm = new TaskManager();
        tm.MsgRedirect(this.UsrMsg);
    }

    public delegate void dlgUsrMsg(string Msg);
    private void UsrMsg(string Msg)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new dlgUsrMsg(UsrMsg), Msg);
            return;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(Msg);

        if (logBox.Text.Length > 20000)
        {
            logBox.Text.Remove(0, 5000);
        }

        logBox.Text += Msg + "\r\n";

        logBox.Select(logBox.Text.Length, 0);
        logBox.ScrollToCaret();
    }
}
```

I can't understand why it's not working. I get the following errors:

1. Error: The best overloaded method match for 'Task.MsgRedirect(Task.UsrMsgDelegate)' has some invalid arguments
2. Error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TaskManager.UsrMsgDelegate' to 'Task.UsrMsgDelegate'

Are there any suggestions for what's going wrong?

Also, would it be better from a design perspective to pass messages from Base to Task and then pass the Base and Task messages from Task up to TaskManager? Or is it better to do what I am currently doing, which is passing messages from Task to TaskManager and from Base to TaskManager.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of `MsgRedirect` looks like this:

```
public void MsgRedirect(UsrMsgDelegate msgHandler)
```

but you are calling it like this:

```
tm.MsgRedirect(this.UsrMsg);
```

where `this.UsrMsg` *appears* to be a method with this profile:

```
private void UsrMsg(string Msg)
```

This would be the cause of the first error.

You have also declared your delegate:

```
public delegate void UsrMsgDelegate(string msg);
```

three times once in each of the classes `APIWrapper`, `Task` and `TaskManager`. This could also be a cause of confusion for the compiler - hence the second error.